# Quelle phrase juste pour spécifier un déroulement d'évènements ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Dit-on ?

- durant la première et deuxième année de l'étude

ou bien

- durant les première et deuxième année(s) de l'étude

ou une autre suggestion pour pour parler de quelque chose qui s'est déroulée lors des deux premières années d'une étude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - durant la première et **la** deuxième année de l'étude
> - durant le**s** première et deuxième année**s** de l'étude
> - durant les deux premières années de l'étude

Référence: [oqlf](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3627)

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a qu'à essayer avec un nom dont le pluriel n'est pas un homophone du singulier:

- Le premier et deuxième cheval reçoit une médaille

ou

- Les premier et deuxième chevaux reçoivent une médaille

En fait la première ligne supposerait que le même cheval arrive premier et deuxème...